# How to convert a specific cake recipe I have to make brownies?

Tags: cake, chocolate, brownies

I have a cake recipe which I love it and would like to turn it into brownies. Can someone help me?
- 3 eggs
- 2 cups sugar
- 3 cups flour
- 2 cups powdered chocolate
- 1 cup oil
- 1 cup of bowling water
- 1 tbsp baking powder

Mix eggs, sugar and oil. Add bowling water and let it still for 5 mins. Add flour and chocolate. Mix for 10 to 15 mins. Add baking powder for baking.

Tks!!!!!

Comment: Can you explain why you're trying to convert this recipe rather than finding an actual brownie recipe? You'll have to redo almost every amount and it likely won't be recognizable as the original. You can certainly make this recipe as a one-layer cake and consider it a brownie.

Comment: To put Catija's question another way: is there something special about this recipe? From the ingredients it doesn't look terribly special, so it seems like you could regard just about *any* brownie recipe as a converted version of it.

Comment: I just love the taste in this cake! But thanks anyway!